# Incomplete Implementation warning in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

I have seen other posts, but I'm not sure what they are talking about. I just started Xcode, its new to me. the warning just says "Semantic Issue Incomplete Implementation"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "classOne.h"

@implementation classOne    <------ this is where I get the Warning

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"I am %i years old, and weigh %i lbs.", age, weight);
}

-(void) setAge:(int) a
{
    age = a;
}

-(void) setWeight: (int) w
{
    weight = w;
}
@end
```

then the .h file is below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface classOne : NSObject {

    int age;
    int weight;


} //Person: NSObject

-(void) print;
-(void) setAge: (int) a;   //same as  void setAge(int a);
-(void) setWight: (int) w;  //same as  void setWeight(int a);
@end
```

---

The main file is this below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "classOne.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {
    classOne *Trenton;

    Trenton = [classOne alloc]; //reserves memory for the object Trenton
    Trenton = [Trenton init];   //initalizes the object

    [Trenton setAge: 25];
    [Trenton setWight: 230];
    [Trenton print];
    //[Trenton release]; //release frees any memory we borrowed from alloc
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it probably mean that your classOne.m is missing a method declared in the classOne.h

Comment: can you provide the wanring text. I suspect that you are missing part of your properties.

Comment: Click on the yellow triangle sign with the exclamation mark in it. Then klick on "reveal in issue navigator" and there xcode tells you what is missing in the implementation of the class.

Comment: Don't start local / instance variables with capitals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spell methods the same in the `@interface` and in the `@implementation`. Looks like you forgot the `e` in `setWeight:`

```
 -(void) setWight: (int) w;  //same as  void setWeight(int a);
```

The compiler is warning you because, based on this typo in your `@interface` declaration, it's expecting for you to implement a method named `setWight:`, but you've implemented `setWeight:`.

Comment: I thought it was something small..... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, find the warning in the warning tab of the left sidebar (it's the 4th icon from the left, the one that looks like `/!\`), and click the little triangle next to it. It will list all the missing methods.

Comment: There is not much mentioned next to the triangle. But there is something like "reveal in issue navigator". And the issue navigator will then provide all the details, especially the name(s) of the missing method(s).

Comment: @HermannKlecker, next to the triangle is just the same message, but if you click that triangle, you'll get the list of unimplemented methods, just like  you would by using the issue navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface either has methods defined in the interface that aren't present in the implementation, or your interface has declared that it implements a protocol, that protocol has required methods, and you haven't implemented them in your implementation file.